# Prometheus log metric exporter

Tags: go, logging, log4j, prometheus

I used Prometheus in a Java app to monitor the different number of logs in my system.

Once I added `<Prometheus name="METRICS"/>` to my `log4j.xml` appenders configuration my Prometheus metrics were populated with the number of info/error/debug messages that were logged in my system.

This was very helpful. I am trying to achieve the same functionality in a golang microservice which uses the default golang log.

Is there any native prometheus support for this kind of functionality or do i need to implement it myself?

Comment: Just to save your time before anyone else answers this, you can search on their Github, if they offer such a functionality - https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus

Answer (score 0):

[Logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) doesn't offer any hooks, so there's no way to create such a thing. What you'd want to do is put a wrapper on top of it, or use a different logging system.